# cmake CheckIncludeFiles fatal error sys/tree.h No such file or directory while the file exists

Tags: c++

Clearwater sprout project contains a lot modules. One of them is libevhtp, at [Github libevhtp](https://github.com/Metaswitch/libevhtp/blob/89b32b5435ea59da54876813f6d34128961c607c/CMakeLists.txt).

> INCLUDE (CheckIncludeFiles)
>
> CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES(sys/tree.h HAVE_SYS_TREE)
>
> if (NOT HAVE_SYS_TREE)
>
> CONFIGURE_FILE(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/compat/sys/tree.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/compat/sys/tree.h)
>
> endif(NOT HAVE_SYS_TREE)

- In wsl Ubuntu, system does not have `sys/tree.h`, so it uses `build/libevhtp/compat/sys/tree.h` to compile. And it compiles successfully.
- In CentOS, system does not have `sys/tree.h` either, but instead of using `build/libevhtp/compat/sys/tree.h`, cmake gives an error:

> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec667563402.dir/CheckIncludeFiles.c.o
> /bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec667563402.dir/CheckIncludeFiles.c.o   -c /home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/build/libevhtp/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFiles.c
> /home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/build/libevhtp/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFiles.c:2:22: fatal error: sys/tree.h: No such file or directory
> #include <sys/tree.h>

I checked CMakeCache.txt in both WSL and CentOS, they are the same:

```
HAVE_SYS_TREE:INTERNAL=
```

Comment: I finally found a solution and perhaps the reason. On wsl Ubuntu, cmake version is 3.16.3, but on CentOS cmake version is 2.8.12.2. That is why they behave differently. The lower version cmake stops when it finds a header not exists. So I delete that `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES`

Comment: About cmake : Suggest `yum install cmake3` .... from the EPEL.repo https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL ..... and use `cmake3 ../` to configure applications.